# Evaluation of $~y_k~$with $~y_{k+1}=(1-h)y_{k}-h~$ where $~k\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq0},~~y_0=0,~~h=\text{non-zero constant} $

Tags: recurrence-relations

$$
y_{k+1}=(1-h)y_{k}-h~~\text{where} ~~k\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq0},~~y_0=0,~~h=\text{non-zero constant} 
$$

I want to evaluate the general term of the sequence $~\{y\}~$

$$\begin{align}
y_0&=0\\
y_1&=(1-h)y_0-h=-h\\
y_2&=(1-h)y_1-h\\&=(1-h)(-h)+(-h)\\
&=(-h)(1-h+1)\\
&=(-h)(2-h)\\
y_3&=(1-h)h_2-h\\
&=(1-h)(-h)(2-h)-h\\
&=(-h)\left\{ (1-h)(2-h)+1 \right\}\\
&=(-h) \left\{ 2-3h+h^2+1 \right\}\\
&=(-h)\left(h^2-3h+3 \right)\\
y_4&=(-h)\left\{ (1-h) \left(h^2-3h+3 \right) +1\right\}\\
&=(-h) \left\{ -h^3+3h^2-6h+4 \right\} 
\end{align}$$

$$
\begin{cases}
  y_0=0\\
  y_1=-h\\
  y_2=(-h)(2-h)\\
  y_3=(-h)\left(h^2-3h+3 \right)\\
  y_4=(-h)\left\{ -h^3+3h^2-6h+4 \right\} 
\end{cases}
$$

I've failed to estimate the general term $~ y_k ~$

I need your help.

BTW the problem statement precedes the following problem statement(I've already solved this problem(though I haven't checked that my soln for it is correct)).

$$
\text{Evaluate}~~y(x)~~\text{of}~~y'=-y-1~~\wedge~~y(0)=0
$$

Can this help to solve the initially given problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
y_{k+1}+1=(1-h)(y_k+1).
$$

We obtain $y_k=(1-h)^k-1$ (when $h\ne1$). If $h=1$ then $y_0=0$, $y_k=-1(k\ge1)$.